# Getting Store error after using Redux Provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

<kbd>index.js</kbd>

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import  store  from "./store"; //error is coming from this part
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';

store.subscribe(()=>console.log(store.getState()));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider>
    <App store={store}/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

<kbd>store.js</kbd>

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";

const store = createStore(rootReducer,  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());

export default store;
```

Before using Provider when I'm  trying to console the store it was working fine but when I'm trying to use Provider , it is giving me an

### Error

```
TypeError: store is undefined
Provider/previousState<
D:/ReactRedux/reduxapp/node_modules/react-redux/es/components/Provider.js:20

  17 |   };
  18 | }, [store]);
  19 | var previousState = useMemo(function () {
> 20 |   return store.getState();
     | ^  21 | }, [store]);
  22 | useIsomorphicLayoutEffect(function () {
  23 |   var subscription = contextValue.subscription;
```

Comment: You have to add `store={store}` on the `Provider` component not on the `App`

Comment: ```<Provider store={store}>``` something like this

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `store` as a `props` to the `Provider` component not on the `App`.

[React redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider)

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```